# XSD: difference between Element and Attribute

Tags: xsd

I'm new to XSD, and I'm quite confused as to when to use attribute, and when to use element?

Why cant we specify minOccurs and maxOccurs in attribute?

Also, why is it we cannot specify use="required" in element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML attribute vs XML element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746/xml-attribute-vs-xml-element)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

An element is an XML element - a opening tag, some content, a closing tag - they are the building blocks of your XML document:

```
<test>someValue</test>
```

Here, "test" would be an element.

Attributes is an additional info on a tag - it's an "add-on" or an extra info on an element, but can never exist alone:

```
<test id="5">somevalue</test>
```

"id" is an attribute.

You cannot have multiple attributes of the same name on a single tag --> minOccurs/maxOccurs makes no sense. You can define required (or not) for an attribute - anything else doesn't make sense.

The elements are defined by their occurrence inside complex types - e.g. if you have a complex type with a `<xs:sequence>` inside - you are defining that all elements must be present and must the in this particular order:

```
<xs:complexType name="SomeType">
   <xs:sequence>       
      <xs:element name="Element1" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="Element2" type="xs:string" />
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Inside an element of that type, the sub-elements "Element1" and "Element2" are required and must appear in this order - there's no need for "required" or not (like with attributes). Whether or not an element is required is defined by the use of minOccurs and maxOccurs; both are =1 by default, e.g. the element must occur, and can only occur once. By tweaking those settings, you can define an element to be optional (minOccurs=0), or allow it to show up several times (maxOccurs > 1).

I'd strongly recommend you check out the [W3Schools Tutorial on XML Schema](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp) and learn some more about XML schema.

Marc

Answer (score 5):

**Example: XSD Format**

```
<xs:complexType name="contactInformation">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="workCountryId" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:all>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

**XML Format**

```
<contactInformation id=100>
    <firstname>VELU</firstname>
    <workCountryId>120</workCountryId>
</contactInformation>
```

`attribute` is optional by default. To specify that the attribute is required, use the `use` attribute:

e.g.   `<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:long" use="required"/>`

More about [attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_simple_attributes.asp) and [elements](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_simple.asp). 
 
A `complexType` element is an XML element that contains other elements and/or attributes.

The `all` element specifies that the child elements can appear in any order and that each child element can occur zero or one time.

`maxOccurs` Optional. Specifies the maximum number of times the element can occur. The value must be 1.

`minOccurs` Optional. Specifies the minimum number of times the element can occur. The value can be 0 or 1. Default value is 1

Comment: Working links for [Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/schema_simple.asp) and [Attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_simple_attributes.asp)

Answer (score 4):

An element is an XML node - and it can contain other nodes, or attributes.  It can be a simple type or a complex type.  It is an XML entity.

An attribute is a descriptor.  It can't contain anything and can only be a simple type.

Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0tkwcx%28VS.80%29.aspx).  Of course, you can just google something like "XML element vs attribute"

Comment: Unlike the other replies, who seem to try to explain *how* to define an element/attribute, you are to the point.

Answer (score 3):

```
<element myAttribute="value">
   <subElement />
   <subElement anotherAttribute="this is an attribute's value">Element value</subElement>
</element>
```

You can't have more than one attribute with the same name in XML, therefore you can't use minOccurs and maxOccurs for attributes.

You don't need use="required" for elements because you can have minOccurs="1" instead.

It is your choice when to use attributes and when to use elements. Here are some guidelines: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-eleatt.html