# Can't deserialize an element if declared as attribute in my class and appears as element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I'm receiving XML files with different layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <PInstrument>
        <Type>myType</Type>
        <Data>
            <PB>blabla</PB>
            <MP>blabla</MP>
            <Mode>blabla</Mode>
        </Data>
    </PInstrument>
</Response>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <PInstrument>
        <Type>myType</Type>
        <Data PB="blabla" MP="blabla" Mode="blabla" />
    </PInstrument>
</Response>
```

In XML both are perfectly correct, but here data contains either attributes or elements.

In .NET, to retrieve the XML inside an object, I must declare it but must specify whether this is an element or an attribute. As a matter of fact the XSD defines what's inside data as attributes so XSD created them as attributes.

But when I read the XML where they are elements, they simply don't populate as if the `XmlDeserialize` made a difference, though there's not in the standard as indicated in the W3C specs.

Why is .NET forcing elements to be elements and attributes to be attributes?

Is there a way to deserialize the file no matter the representation (attribute or element)?

Comment: Xml Serialization is not meant for random XML file.  The xml file for serialization to work must always be well structured.

Answer (score 1):

I would use json for example

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    var x = XElement.Parse(xml);

    var response =  JsonConvert
                   .DeserializeObject<Root>(JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(x)
                   .Replace("\"@", "\""));
```

c# classes

```
public class Root
{
    public Response Response { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string PB { get; set; }
    public string MP { get; set; }
    public string Mode { get; set; }
}

public class PInstrument
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public PInstrument PInstrument { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's interesting to consider using JSON to work with XML but there's a point here indeed. I'm going to investigate that

Answer (score 1):

An attribute and child element of an XML element can have the **same name**, which may be one reason why .NET forces elements to be elements and attributes to be attributes.<sup>[1]</sup>  I.e. the following is perfectly well-formed XML

```xml
<Data PB="foo">
  <PB>bar</PB>
</Data>
```

`XmlSerializer` allows you to bind to both the `PB` attribute and child element to distinct .NET properties.

In fact, this provides a workaround for your problem: you could create surrogate properties for each attribute that redirect the value of each to the property binding to the corresponding element, like so:

```
[XmlRoot("Data")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement("PB")] public string PB { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("MP")] public string MP { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Mode")] public string Mode { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("PB")] public string PBAttribute { get => PB; set => PB = value; }
    [XmlAttribute("MP")] public string MPAttribute { get => MP; set => MP = value; }
    [XmlAttribute("Mode")] public string ModeAttribute { get => Mode; set => Mode = value; }

    // Prevent the elements from being re-serialized.
    public bool ShouldSerializePB() => false;
    public bool ShouldSerializeMP() => false;
    public bool ShouldSerializeMode() => false;
}

[XmlRoot("PInstrument")]
public class PInstrument 
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Response")]
public class Response 
{
    public PInstrument PInstrument { get; set; }
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FAzcUz).,

This version of `<Data>` always re-serializes the values as attributes.  If you need to track whether the values were deserialized as attributes or elements and re-serialize accordingly, you could use the [`{PropertyName}Specified`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37842985/3744182) pattern:

```
[XmlRoot("Data")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement("PB")] public string PB { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("MP")] public string MP { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Mode")] public string Mode { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("PB")] public string PBAttribute { get => PB; set => PB = value; }
    [XmlAttribute("MP")] public string MPAttribute { get => MP; set => MP = value; }
    [XmlAttribute("Mode")] public string ModeAttribute { get => Mode; set => Mode = value; }

    [XmlIgnore] public bool PBSpecified { get; set; } = false; // Serialize as attributes unless specified.
    [XmlIgnore] public bool MPSpecified { get; set; } = false;
    [XmlIgnore] public bool ModeSpecified { get; set; } = false;

    [XmlIgnore] public bool PBAttributeSpecified { get => !PBSpecified; set => PBSpecified = !value; }
    [XmlIgnore] public bool MPAttributeSpecified { get => !MPSpecified; set => MPSpecified = !value; }
    [XmlIgnore] public bool ModeAttributeSpecified { get => !ModeSpecified; set => ModeSpecified = !value; }
}
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E6hGux).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Elements and attributes also appear differently in [XSD schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1727468/3744182) and have different restrictions on the types of values they can contain.

Comment: Wow this is an impressive answer and I'm going to give it a try. Actually my classes are created with a modified version, of my own, of XSD.exe to generate classes from a... XSD. I'm going to update the class generator to do as you indicate because they seems pretty neat