# More and more examples saving text data (strings) in an attributes instead of XML text node. Why?

Tags: xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML attribute vs XML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746/xml-attribute-vs-xml-element)

Can someone explain me why more and more examples that I see on the Internet, keeping the  text data in an attribute value instead of text node? Example:

```
<Root>
    <Data Value="blaaa" />
<Root>
```

Instead of this:

```
<Root>
    <Data>Blaaa</Data>
</Root>
```

What are the benefits actually to use attributes? Thanks.

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746/xml-attribute-vs-xml-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about which is beneficial. *Attribute* and *Element* each have their own semantic meaning and purpose.

> **If you consider the information in
>   question to be part of the essential
>   material that is being expressed or
>   communicated in the XML, put it in an
>   element.** For human-readable documents
>   this generally means the core content
>   that is being communicated to the
>   reader. For machine-oriented records
>   formats this generally means the data
>   that comes directly from the problem
>   domain. **If you consider the
>   information to be peripheral or
>   incidental to the main communication,
>   or purely intended to help
>   applications process the main
>   communication, use attributes.** This
>   avoids cluttering up the core content
>   with auxiliary material. For
>   machine-oriented records formats, this
>   generally means application-specific
>   notations on the main data from the
>   problem-domain.

Source: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-eleatt.html

Answer (score 0):

There are no major benefits aside from granularity, aesthetics, and personal preference. Personally I prefer the nested elements over attributes, I feel like it gives me more control on the application side. For more detailed reading here is an article from IBM: [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-eleatt.html) and here is a quicker read: [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/DTD/dtd_el_vs_attr.asp). Truly it boils down to personal preference though.