# Is processing of "attribute" different from "element"

Tags: xml, xsd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML attribute vs XML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746/xml-attribute-vs-xml-element)

I was informed to use attributes for metadata and elements for data. I was wondering what are the benefits of separating elements from attributes. Are attributes processed differently than the elements in XML?

Thanks,
Mohmd.

Comment: How they are processed depends entirely on how you define them? There is no rule on how to process an xml but its definition (xsd).

Answer (score -1):

> Some of the problems with attributes are:
>
> - attributes cannot contain multiple values (child elements can)
> - attributes are not easily expandable (for future changes)
> - attributes cannot describe structures (child elements can)
>
> Metadata (data about data) should be stored as attributes, and that data itself should be stored as elements.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/DTD/dtd_el_vs_attr.asp

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community.

Comment: @Kev, I copied my own answer and added string to newer post, so it isn't exact duplicate... :-)

Comment: @Kev, 90% of questions in SO are duplicates...., therefore they have similar answers.