# XML attributes <item id="1"> vs <id> 1 </id>

Tags: php, xml, append

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML attribute vs XML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746/xml-attribute-vs-xml-element)

What is the difference between snippet "A":

```
<root>
    <item id="1">
        <attr1> foo </attr1>
        <attr2> bar </attr2>
    </item>
</root>
```

and placing the "id" attribute within the element in snippet "B":

```
<root>
    <item>
        <id> 1 </id>
        <attr1> foo </attr1>
        <attr2> bar </attr2>
    </item>
</root>
```

and how would I add the attribute "id" when creating xml with PHP in snippet "A" assuming I can already create the format of snippet "B" just fine using DOM's `createElement()` and `appendChild`?

Thanks!

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php

Comment: *(google)* [when+to+use+attributes+vs+elements](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=when+to+use+attributes+vs+elements)

Comment: I didn't know the actual terminology, I apologize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"id" is an attribute in snippet "A" and a node in snippet "B". You can use [`setAttribute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php) to add this.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had no idea what they were or what they were called (thus I couldn't search for them). Apparently that is almost a crime on S.O. considering the downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Use setAttribute to add the attribute to the DOM element:

```
$domNode->setAttribute("id", "youridvalue");
```

The only difference between the two is the syntax used to get the values back, and in one you're adding an attribute, the other you're adding a tag. Either works, I prefer attributes.

Comment: The difference is not merely syntactical. You can use a CDATA section inside an element, but not an attribute. Also the attribute should be unique across the whole document and is the subject of special processing: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-id/#processing

Answer (score 1):

You can call `$element->setAttribute($name, $value)` after you have created the id element