# In XML DTD, how can an attribute have two values?

Tags: xml, dtd

Trying to achieve something like this

```
ATTLIST employee role (leader|analyst|leader,analyst)
```

where I can't change it into an element; it needs to be an attribute.

It seems like DTD doesn't like commas in its expressions.

Comment: Use spaces instead of commas. That's how html class attribute works. Though technically it's simply defined as a string rather than having any structure in the xhtml DTD

Answer (score 1):

An attribute in XML cannot contain elements.

You're really going against the grain to try to add structure to attributes in any way.  If you must do it, keep it simple:  You can represent a list via space or comma-separated values.  Going any further runs into requiring a separate micro-parser distinct from an XML parser just to parse the attribute values.  It's not a good idea, and don't expect support from DTD beyond that which is provided by `NMTOKENS`, `IDREFS`, or `ENTITIES`

See also: [XML Element vs XML Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23133755/290085)

Comment: If you were using XML Schema to describe the document, then you could use a `list` type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
<!ATTLIST employee role (leader|analyst|leader) "analyst">
```