# What's the difference in DTD between !ELEMENT and !ATTLIST

Tags: xml, dtd

There are 3 variants for an XML file. What's the difference between them and which should I use?

1. `<!ELEMENT Name (#PCDATA)>`
2. `<!ELEMENT Name (First, Last)>
    <!ELEMENT First (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT Last (#PCDATA)>`
3. `<!ELEMENT Name EMPTY> 
    <!ATTLIST Name 
       First CDATA #REQUIRED
       Last CDATA #REQUIRED >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **second** and **third cases** amount to the distinction between [***XML attributes vs XML elements***](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33746/290085), *which has already been answered extensively in the linked question.*

Your **first case** introduces the possibility of not marking up a name into separate first and last names.  You ask when you might want to do this.  Generally, name data originates in a form where you have first and last name already determined separately.  Preserving this distinction makes sense.  However, there are some reasons you might want to use a single name field rather than separate first and last names:

- Some people don't have separate first and last names.
- Your data source might not provide separate first and last names, and
  parsing a single name into first and last parts can be very difficult.

These reasons generalize to non-name data.  You will facilitate downstream processing if your markup is at a finer level of granularity, but it's not always easy to achieve that granularity.  There's also a judgement call to be made regarding the likelihood of the *need* for the greater degree of markup by current and future consuming applications.  More markup that's never needed just increases overhead to no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

- **#PCDATA** represents a node's or an attribute's simple string content.
- **!ELEMENT** is mapped to an XML Node:

  `<!ELEMENT Name (#PCDATA)>`:

  `<Name>Tony Stark</Name>`
- **!ATTLIST** is mapped to an XML Node's attributes:

  `<!ELEMENT Name EMPTY> 
  <!ATTLIST Name 
      First CDATA #REQUIRED
      Last CDATA #REQUIRED >`:

  `<Name First="Tony" Last="Stark"/>`

The usage of these is entirely up to you and your use case.