# Proper syntax for XML attributes?

Tags: xml, xml-attribute

I am a beginner in XML language. 
I am learning XML in Android studio at school.

Example,

```
<Person>
 <sex ="female"></sex>
 <firstname = "Hani"></firstname>
 <lastname = "Jeong"></lastname>
</Person>
```

in this case, all the values are hidden from users, right?

What I am really confused about is that I understood that attributes must always have values.

Which common situations do you hide the values or show the values to users?

Comment: **Example #3 is not [well-formed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085), but, overall, this is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746/xml-attribute-vs-xml-element)...**

Comment: Thanks for the resource. Sorry I realized that some of questions were duplicate as you mentioned.

Comment: Your edit moves your question away from being a duplicate but still doesn't address the problem of your XML still being not well-formed.  I'll try to explain in an answer below, but you ought to do some basic introductory XML reading.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML is not [***well-formed***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).

You'll have to change it to use elements,

```
<Person>
 <sex>female</sex>
 <firstname>Hani</firstname>
 <lastname>Jeong</lastname>
</Person>
```

or attributes,

```
<Person sex="female"
        firstname="Hani"      
        lastname="Jeong"/>
```

or some combination thereof.

See also:  [XML attribute vs XML element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33746/290085)

> What I am really confused about is that I understood that attributes
>   must always have values.

Yes, for example, this would not be allowed:

```
<Person sex/>
```

But note that these could be ok,

```
<Person sex=""/>
<Person sex="unknown"/>
```

As could omitting the attribute altogether,

```
<Person/>
```

> Which common situations do you hide the values or show the values to
>   users?

The above alternatives are design choices that depend upon your data, your intent, and any associated schemas or conventions you seek to follow.