# Is complexType allowed as attribute content?

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl

I have a WSDL/XSD from client and try to import using wsimport, and it complains:

```
[ERROR] Unexpected <complexType> appears at line 508 column 33
```

I checked the file and it shows:

```
   <complexType name="ActionInfo">
    <sequence/>
    <attribute name="action">
     <complexType name="string">
      <simpleContent>
       <extension/>
      </simpleContent>
     </complexType>
    </attribute>
    <attribute name="type">
     <complexType name="string">
      <simpleContent>
       <extension/>
      </simpleContent>
     </complexType>
    </attribute>
   </complexType>
```

Is this even legal? Apparently this is the xsd I got from their production environment so it somehow works for them.

On the top of their WSDL, it says it is generated by Axis 1.4

Comment: "Works for [us]" is no excuse.  It's wrong.  (It's also doubtful that it truly works for them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Absolutely not.**

Attributes by their very nature cannot have complex content.  The error message is entirely correct: The type definition for an `xs:attribute` [***must be a simple type***](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Attribute_Declaration_details).

See also [XML attribute vs XML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746/xml-attribute-vs-xml-element)