# How do I resolve exception caused by JAXB statement?

Tags: java, android, xml, jaxb

Here is the code I'm trying to run but it is currently throwing an exception at this line:

```
try {
        File file = new File(getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + name + ".xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Restaurant.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(r, file);

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm getting an exception thrown at this line:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Restaurant.class);
```

I copied the log to pastebin (https://pastebin.com/WRjXbub7)

I am trying to serialize an object to a XML file. I'm not getting red marks or anything in my code, so I don't know what the issue is here. Thanks!

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick`

can you send the code where you are setting the onClickListener ?
as your log file suggest exception started from there. And do try clean build also.

Comment: @Anmol in activity xml: `android:onClick="finalizePlace"`  
here is the method declaration:  
`public void finalizePlace(View view)`  
The thing is, There is code above this that works just fine in the method. Also, cleaning the project unfortunately didn't help.

Comment: share cade of `Restaurant` class

Comment: @Anmol https://pastebin.com/q6YHszyd

Comment: try setting the `@XmlElement` on the getter's not on the variable then it should work.And all the variable's are not Element try reading this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33757/7972699   if something helps i will post it as an answer do tell.

Comment: Here is the new log, still getting a exception: https://pastebin.com/cQ02rDsv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185682/discussion-between-anmol-and-kyle-diablo).