# Using similar tags for different objects in XML

Tags: xml

I want to define several non-inherited object types. I want to know whether I can use similar tags for them in XML. Some objects do not have the common tags.
For example, the tag "name" below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stuff>
    <person>
        <name>
            John
        </name>
        <age>
            30
        </age>
    </person>
    <car>
        <name>
            BMW
        </name>
        <price>
            50000
        </price>
    </car>
    <book>
        <name>
            Harry Potter
        </name>
        <author>
            Rowling
        </author>
    </book>
    <city>
        <country>
            USA
        </country>
        <population>
            5000000
        </population>
    </city>
</stuff>
```

Do we encounter any problems?
In case of no theoretical error, can it make a "misunderstanding" in a large XML?
Can it be problematic when we try to convert this XML to formats like SQL, Excel, Access, MongoDB etc?

Comment: You only might have problems validating this XML.  A good XML is _documented_ by an [XSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)), which defines (to keep this comment short) if tags are mandatory, or not .

Comment: @Luuk: There's no problem defining an XSD for such an XML document.  Perhaps you're thinking of same-named *sibling* elements with different content models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a same-named element (such as your `name` example) as a child of two ***different*** parent elements such as `person` and `car` is natural and fully supported by XML and its related standards:

- DTD supports defining same-named elements with different parents

```
  <!DOCTYPE people_list [
    <!ELEMENT person (name, age)>
    <!ELEMENT car (name, price)>
    <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT age (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
  ]>
```

- XSD supports it too: See [Basic Concepts: The Purchase Order](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#PO) in the XSD primer.
- XPath (and therefore XSLT) differentiates between `/stuff/person/name` versus `/stuff/car/name`.
- Etcetera.

Note that the content models of `name` could even be different for the `name` of a `person` vs the `name` of a `car`.  *Well-formed* XML allows the content models to differ for same-named elements with the ***same*** parent even, but XML schemas (such as DTD and XSD) generally do not support the definition of such elements, so such XML would generally not be able to be considered *valid*.

### See also

- [Is there any difference between 'valid xml' and 'well formed xml'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134494/290085)
- [XML attribute vs XML element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33746/290085)

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any problem working with the above xml, you will have to query into object and create a table / collection for each.

Or

Create a type field for each and store them in the same table/collection

```
{ "type": "person", "name": "John", "age": 30 }
{ "type": "car", "name": "BMW", "price": 50000 }
{ "type": "book", "name": "Harry Potter", "author": "Rowling" }
```